# Identifying rows in a data frame that have more than one duplicate and count them

Tags: r

I have a problem with this data frame, that is alocated in this link:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/83787253/Base.RData

My problem is that I want to identify rows that have more than one duplicate. I used this code for to solve my problem but It counts all rows, including the rows that are uniques.

```
z1=data.frame(ddply(Base, .(TIPO_MOVIMIENTO,FECHA.DE.PROCESO.DEL.SISTEMA.DEL.MOVIMIENTO,FECHA.REAL.DEL.MOVIMIENTO,VALOR_TOTAL_MOVIMIENTO,NOMBRE.DEL.MOVIMIENTO.Y.NTAD.NTAC,ID,Categoria),summarise,X=length(ID)))
```

It works but I dont know how to get only rows that have more than one duplicates. Thanks

Comment: Should ID 003 just have 1 duplicate?

Comment: what would you do if there was two more rows like this: `001 30, 001 30`?

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` answer

```
DT <- data.table(d, key = 'ID')
DTu <- unique(DT)[,N:=0L][DT[, .N,by = list(ID, Amount)][N >1], N := i.N]
DTu
##     ID Amount N
## 1: 001     10 2
## 2: 002     20 0
## 3: 003     50 2
## 4: 004     30 0
```

This creates a unique `data.table` (based on the key), the sets `N=0` within that data.table, it then joins with a data.table that has counted the number of rows is subset to contain those counts above 1, it then assigns this new count within the unique data.table, overwriting N=0 with the correct number.

A second, perhaps simpler approach (using the updated data in the question, which includes a class column)

```
 DT[, .N  ,by = list(ID, Class)][,list(dups = sum(N[N>1])) ,by= ID]
    ID dups
1: 001    2
2: 002    0
3: 003    2
4: 004    0
```

Comment: thanks and what happen in the case when there is unique register. I saw it doesn't count it???

Comment: @user2080848 -- I have no idea what that comment means. If you have a more complex case that you wish to address, please edit your question and include these data and your expected outcome.